# Configure eslint to read common types in src/types/types.d.ts vue3

Tags: vuejs3, eslintrc

My eslint .eslintrc.js, now properly in the src folder, is the following:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'standard',
    'prettier'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    'ecmaFeatures': {
      'jsx': true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  rules: {
    'import/no-unresolved': 'error'
  },
  settings: {
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      'typescript': {
        'alwaysTryTypes': true, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to use eslint-import-resolver-typescript, but the documentation is a bit opaque.

I currently get errors on lines where a externally defined type is used (StepData in this example):

```
setup() {
   const data = inject("StepData") as StepData;
   return {
     data,
   };
},
```

Comment: One clue is that if I remove eslint from vite.config.ts, it runs fine. If I make any changes as suggested by eslint when it is setup, the errors persist even after I make changes. If I then switch back to compiling without eslint, and run **npm run dev** tthe lint changes are reflected the next time I switch it back to running eslint. So it looks like it is not compiling the code before it does the lint checks.

Comment: Another clue is that running tests manually separately from npm run dev works just fine.

Comment: One thing that caused the above confusion is that cls doesn't actually clear the screen in the command window of Visual Studio Code. So the previous run is still listed even though it temporarily disappeared when cls was executed. So my temporary fix is to eliminate eslintPlugin from vite.config. This way it at least runs and I can ignore the errors when doing npm run lint.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was the following. In types.d.ts (or other file if you want to have different collections of your custom types):

```
export interface MyType {
  positioner: DOMRect;
  content: DOMRect;
  arrow: DOMRect;
  window: DOMRect;
}

export interface SomeOtherType {
.. and so on
```

Then in the .vue files, import the types I need for the component:

```
import type { MyType, SomeOtherType } from "../types/types";
```

Before I was not using the export keyword and the types just worked without being imported. They have to be imported like this if you use export. It's kind of amazing how you are just expected to know this, the documentation for Typescript or Vue is sorely lacking in examples.